# Replacing cpu Thermal paste triggered the AppleThunderboltNHI.kext problem?

Tags: crash, thunderbolt

This is a Macbook pro 2014-mid 15 inch.
After I replaced the cpu thermal paste, it starts to auto shutdown frequently. I have monitored the cpu temperature to find out that it is better than before.
When it is connect to a monitor through thunderbolt cable, it works normally.
There was no such auto-shutdown problem before that. I googled to get the clue about AppleThunderboltNHI.kext.
I tried to disable the kext, the problem disappeared. But I need Thunderbolt-Network-Adapter.
And I wondering what happened, why the problem came out after replacing thermal paste.

Comment: This begs the question *why* the thermal paste was replaced. It sounds like your problems began with replacing the thermal paste and it sounds like all of your problems can be traced back to that one modification, as they all started immediately after that was done.

Comment: The cpu temperature was 90° even while idling. After replacing thermal paste, it becomes around 50°.

Comment: It seems likely that something got damaged or unplugged during the thermal paste replacement. Can you reopen the laptop and check all the wires?

Comment: I have checked the cables and plugs, it seems that all are plugged correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what really happened, the problem disappeared. What I did is that I used a paper to clean up the dusts around the three FDMF6808 chips.